# angularjs filter firebase child and value

Tags: html, angularjs, firebase

I'm currently trying to filter my firebase values.

I'm trying by specifying the value in my ng-repeat like so:

```
<div class="searchHPerson" ng-repeat="result in results | filter: {dim1:'N'}:true">

        <div class="searchSingleDiv">
          <h6>{{result.name}}</h6>
          <img class="hUserImg" src="{{result.img}}"></img>
        </div>

</div>
```

This works indeed, but I'd like to pass a value to the filter by my $scope, like so:

```
<div class="searchHPerson" ng-repeat="result in results | filter: {dim1:'{{search}}'}:true">

        <div class="searchSingleDiv">
          <h6>{{result.name}}</h6>
          <img class="hUserImg" src="{{result.img}}"></img>
        </div>

</div>
```

... Doesn't work. This is my js code:

```
$scope.showResults = function() {
  totalQuery = day + week;
  totalValue = time1 + time2 + time3 + time4;

  $scope.search = totalValue;

  var Rref = firebase.database().ref().child('Users');

  $scope.search = totalValue;
  $scope.results = $firebaseArray(Rref);

}
```

**My question**
How can I pass a search value from my js to my ng-repeat filter?

Thank you in advance,
Have a good day/evening/night!

Comment: `filter: {dim1: search}:true`?